# Self adjoint map are bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $H$ is a Hilbert space and $T:H\rightarrow H$ that is self-adjoint. How to prove that $T$ is bounded operator.

Does the following argument work?

For all $x,y\in \mathcal{H}$
$$\|Tx\|=\sup_{||y||=1}|\langle Tx,y\rangle|\leq \|Ty\|\cdot \|x\|$$
for any fixed $x$. So $\sup_y\|T\|<\infty$, UBP implies that there is a constant $c$. $||Tx||\leq c||x||$?

Any feedback? Thanks

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense. You haven't defined $y$, $J_x$, or $c$, and the expression $\sup_x\|T\|$ is probably not what was meant since $\|T\|$ does not depend on $x$.

Comment: $J_x$ is a typo$

Comment: How are you getting $\|Tx\|=|\langle Tx,y\rangle|$?

Comment: Look up Hellinger–Toeplitz theorem.

Comment: @BrentKerby, sorry for the mess, my computer deleted the sup part by accident

Comment: As written, it still doesn't make sense; for example, $y$ appears free in $\|Ty\|\cdot\|x\|$ and yet it is bound in the sup on the other side of the inequality. I think you want to define a collection of linear functionals $T_y$ by $T_y(x)=\langle Tx, y\rangle$ and apply UBP to those.

Comment: @BrentKerby Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to show the operator is closed?